# Xpath: How to use wildcard or regex to match text()?

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<span> GDP, By Country, 2015 As Base Year </span>

<span> GDP, By City, 2015 As Base Year </span>

<span> GDP, 2015 As Base Year</span>

Other span tags starting with "GDP" and ending with "2015 As Base Year"
```

I want to match "GDP, 2015 As Base Year"

I can use

`//span[text()='GDP, 2015 As Base Year']`

But 2015 could change in the future.

I am using Selenium with Chrome and "find_element_by_xpath". So how do I use wildcard or regex to construct a more robust selector?

I tried
 `//span[matches(text(), 'GDP, \d+ As Base Year')]`

But get error:
**The string '//span[matches(text(), 'GDP, \d+ As Base Year')]' is not a valid XPath expression.**

Answer (score 2):

`matches()` is xpath 2 function, Selenium supports xpath 1. You could however use something like

```
//span[boolean(number(substring-before(substring-after(., "GDP, "), "As Base Year")))]
```

`substring-after(., "GDP, ")` will return a partial text after `"GDP, "`, `"2015 As Base Year"`

`substring-before("2015 As Base Year", "As Base Year")` will return `"2015 "`

`number()` will return an `int` if the text can be converted to number, else `NaN`

`boolean()` will check if the converted text has value and it's not `NaN.

Answer (score 0):

A easier approach would be to include both the substring **GDP** and **As Base Year** as follows:

- Using *`starts-with()`* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  //span[starts-with(., 'GDP') and contains(., 'As Base Year')]
  ```
- Using *`contains()`* twice:

  ```
  //span[contains(., 'GDP') and contains(., 'As Base Year')]
  ```
- Simply using the text ***As Base Year***:

  ```
  //span[contains(., 'As Base Year')]
  ```

Comment: This will match all the `<span>` tags, the OP is looking for a specific text `"GDP, 2015 As Base Year"`

Comment: I think not all the _`<span>`_ ends with the innerText _**".... As Base Year"**_

Comment: All the tags in the example are, and he/she also wrote *Other span tags starting with "GDP" and ending with "2015 As Base Year"*

Comment: No, I haven't included the substring _`2015`_ as OP mentioned _...But 2015 could change in the future..._